# web-mode sql detection doesn't activate syntax highlighting

Tags: syntax-highlighting, web-mode

we edit freemarker template engine files with web-mode.
The files also contain a lot of SQL.
I added

```
    (defun my-web-mode-hook ()
    "Hooks for Web mode."
    (setq web-mode-enable-sql-detection t)
    )
    (add-hook 'web-mode-hook  'my-web-mode-hook)
```

to .emacs file, but don't geht syntax highlighting for the SQL.

Is it possible to highlight freemarker as well as SQL-Code?

Thanks for any suggestion

Meikel

Comment: Would you mind giving us some sample code so we can test the highlighting ourselves?